# Can't Italicize in a particular document in Pages '09

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, iwork-pages

I have a document open in Apple's Pages '09, and for some reason I can't italicize the words. The button for italicize simply doesn't work, but Bold and Underline does. Is there any generic solution to this problem? Restarting Pages doesn't work, and the problem only exists in one document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe I didn't detect this earlier: The font I was using "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro" doesn't support italicizing, which is probably why. Fixed it!

Comment: @Nano8Blazex: all you have to do is mark your answer as "accepted"; there's no need to delete it.

Comment: Ok. Well, I have to wait 2 days :)